Parameter derivative of the confluent hypergeometric function
Let $X$ follow a normal distribution with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$. Mathematica gives
$$
E[\log|1+X|]=\frac{1}{2}\biggl(-\gamma-\log 2+2\log\sigma-\frac{\partial}{\partial a}{}_1 F_1\biggl(0,\frac{1}{2},-\frac{(1+\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}\biggr)\biggr),
$$
where $\gamma$ is Euler's gamma and ${}_1 F_1(a,b,z)$ the confluent hypergeometric function.
I want to know the condition on $(\mu,\sigma^2)$ under which $E[\log|1+X|]<0$. For this, I need to know how
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial a}{}_1 F_1\biggl(0,\frac{1}{2},-z\biggr)
$$
behaves for $z>0$.
I found this paper that derives some formula for this, but the case with $a=0$ does not seem to be covered in the expression I can understand "(6a)".
Does anyone have a suggestion on how to proceed?

Eq. (38a) in the paper, that you linked in your question, seems to give the solution to your problem. Btw, here is a link to that paper without paywall https://www.researchgate.net/publication/234904587_Derivatives_of_any_order_of_the_confluent_hypergeometric_function_1F1abz_with_respect_to_the_parameter_a_or_b

Thank you! I must have overlooked it.
